# Как сделать чтобы телеграмм бот удалял сообщения с ссылками Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы бот удалял плохие сообщения, но не получается сделать нормально.

Вот код:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_message(message: types.Message):
    if "https" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
```

Comment: Что значит "плохие"?

Comment: матные, или к примеру ссылки @oleksandrigo

Comment: Для этого вы должны использовать мидлвари

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так. Эта мидлварь будет удалять все ссылки

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import MessageEntityType


class UrlMiddleWare(BaseMiddleware):
    async def on_pre_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
        if msg_entities := (message.entities or message.caption_entities):
            for entitie in msg_entities:
                if entitie.type in [MessageEntityType.URL, MessageEntityType.TEXT_LINK]:
                    await message.delete()
                    raise CancelHandler()

# dp - экземпляр диспатчера
dp.setup_middleware(UrlMiddleWare())
```

Если нужно чтобы он удалял еще и маты то лучше добавить еще одну мидлварь, которая будет проверять текст сообщения на наличие мата.